# regex with query string containing?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect the following URL:
url/efx.aspx?xxxxxxx
to url/car-audio/efx-hardware/amp-install-kits

However it is redirecting whatever contains efx.aspx with the letters without the ? sign. I was wondering how I can fix this?

```
for example it is redirecting the following:
domain.com/efx.aspxlsdkjfhlasdf
but it is not redirecting
domain.com/efx.aspx?lsdkjfhlasdf
```

here is the .htaccess rule I wrote. how can I correct it?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /efx.aspx[^/]+$
RewriteRule (.*) /car-audio/efx-hardware/amp-install-kits [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^efx\.aspx$ /car-audio/efx-hardware/amp-install-kits? [R=301,NC,L]
```

- Query string is not part of `REQUEST_URI` hence `[^/]+` after `efx.aspx` fails your rule.
- Also `?` at the end of target URI removes any existing query string.